# HtpContext.Current is null when calling from web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My project structure in brief.

I have an `Angular2` app, that calls `WebApi`, that calls code from another project say (`CommonProj`). `CommonProj` code is accessing session as below.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] != null)
{
    // code
}
```

but it gives me Null Reference error because `HttpContext.Current` is null. When this code is called from other place i.e. non api it works fine. My question is how to access `HttpContext.Current` in explained situation.

Comment: I think this is a dupe. See accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884619/is-it-possible-to-access-httpcontext-current-session-from-web-api

Comment: @AndyNichols Request is the property of `HttpContext.Current`, so the same problem will be there too.